# SQL - using null as a wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm joining two tables, Linnmon and Tarendo.

```
SELECT
  Linnmon.ID         AS Linnmon,
  COUNT(Tarrendo.ID) AS Tarrendous
FROM
( SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT 1 AS ID, 'RED'  AS Colour FROM Dual)
  UNION (SELECT 2 AS ID, 'BLUE' AS Colour FROM Dual)
  UNION (SELECT 3 AS ID,  null  AS Colour FROM Dual)
) Linnmon
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tarendo
ON Tarendo.Colour = Linnmon.Colour
```

`Linnmon.Colour:null` is meant to be a wildcard and match any `Tarendo.Colour`, so:

```
ON Tarendo.Colour = NVL(Linnmon.Colour, Tarendo.Colour)
```

However today I'm dealing with data where `Tarendo.Colour` can be `null`, and I want to match `Linnmon.Colour:null` with any value for `Tarendo.Colour` including `null`.

I came up with this, which works, but using a string literal and so many `NVL`s feels wrong - is there a better way?

```
ON NVL(Tarendo.Colour, 'asdf') = NVL(Linnmon.Colour, NVL(Tarendo.Colour, 'asdf'))
```

Given I've assembled `Linnmon` myself - a DIY assembly within my own SQL statement - I'm not tied to using `null` as a wildcard and if there's a better practice I could do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit logic rather than magical values:

```
ON (Tarendo.Colour = Linnmon.Colour) OR
   (Linnmon.Colour IS NULL)
```

Comment: That's so simple, I'm having a head-table moment.

Answer (score 1):

If Linnmon.Colour IS NULL shall match any Tarendo.Colour, then the `ON` clause becomes:

```
ON Tarendo.Colour = Linnmon.Colour OR Linnmon.Colour IS NULL
```